# Las Node MCU tendrán algún id que las identifique de otra?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

Tengo dos Node MCU Amica y cada una tiene conectado un sensor dht22 y los datos obtenidos los subo a una base de datos MySQL, hasta ahí todo bien, lo que quiero saber es si estas placas tienen algún tipo de id único que las diferencie una de otra y así poder "ligar" los sensores a la placa ?

y si es que se pueden obtener por código para hacerlo mas automático

había encontrado esta librería pero no se si me llegue a servir [Adafruit Unified Sensor Driver](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/blob/master/examples/DHT_Unified_Sensor/DHT_Unified_Sensor.ino)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es mala idea depender del numero serial de un equipo o cpu.

La mejor práctica de ingeniería es que las cosas funcionen sin importar el equipo en particular. Una manera de hacerlo (lo que yo hago), es poner un archivo de configuración JSON en el sistema de archivos del NodeMCU, y que la aplicación cargue su identidad desde ahí.

Por ejemplo, tengo este archivo de configuración para un sensor de temp/humedad, de los cuales hay varios repartidos por la casa:

```
{"ntp_server": "ntp", 
 "mqtt_server": "mqtt", 
 "ssid": "home", 
 "time_zone": -4, 
 "password": "password", 
 "hostname": "sensor1"}
```

La aplicación registra temp/humedad minuto a minuto. Los datos quedan grabados en MySQL en un servidor.

La aplicación carga su configuración TCP/IP por DHCP. El servidor DHCP registra el nombre `sensor1` en la red local, de modo de poder hacer telnet/ftp/http por nombre, no por dirección.

Todas las operaciones (MQTT, BBDD) quedan registradas con el hostname del sensor.

**Identificación en vivo**

Si tienes varios sensores instalados querrán saber cual sensor estás mirando sin tener que desconectarlo.

La solución que uso es que cada aplicación tiene un comando MQTT para hacer parpadear su led de abordo. Cuando necesito ubicar o identificar un sensor en particular, le envio una orden de parpadeo. Es un "ping luminoso"

Comment: si yo coloco un JSON en cada dispositivo NodeMCU a la larga si tuviera muchos se volvería algo tedioso a mi parecer, pero claro citando esto `Es mala idea depender del numero serial de un equipo o cpu.` la NodeMCU se puede dañar por x motivo y el id se perdería

Comment: Además tengo acceso remoto al NodeMCU, y puede actualizar el software/archivo via WiFi. No necesito desmontarlo para actualizarlo.